# Can we move data to Vertica using Spark and without having hadoop as the staging environment?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, vertica

i am trying to stream data in spark and load it into vertica, every article i refer to talks about having hdfs to first persist the data from DF or RDD, is there a way to move data without using Hadoop and any additional data storage

Comment: What version of Spark are you using? And what version of Vertica?

Answer (score 0):

Not with the [Vertica Connector for Apache Spark](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SparkConnector/WritingToVerticaFromSpark.htm), unfortunately that connector does require that data be written to HDFS first.

You can save directly to a JDBC connection table from Spark with `df.write()`.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SQLContext, SaveMode}

df.write
  .mode(SaveMode.Append)
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "jdbc:vertica://vertica:5433/database")
  .option("dbtable", "schema.table")
  .option("user", "dbadmin")
  .option("password", "password")
  .save()
```

This worked for me using Spark version 2.2.1. Vertica version 9.1.

Comment: Thanks, i have spark 2.3 and Vertica is V9, i am currently using S3 for storing data in files and then load into vertica, i am going to try this approach as well, also could you help me understand why in most of the articles it is not recommended to load it directly and instead go via HDFS?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure why it is recommended to save to HDFS first.